# Did Dr. Stein sing so well because of the ingestible translator he was using to speak German?

Tags: character, arrowverse, legends-of-tomorrow

In *DC’s Legends of Tomorrow* episode 2x02 “[Justice Society of America](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/The_Justice_Society_of_America)”, Dr. Martin Stein impersonated singer Max Lorenz to get into a Nazi club. While there, a Nazi army official said that he didn’t believe he was who he said he was, so he asked him to sing.

After a lot of tension where it looked like Stein would be outed, he begins to sing [Edelweiss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edelweiss_(song)) (which he calls “The Sound of Music”) and everyone is pleasantly shocked that he can sing so well. By the end, the Nazi official is actually in tears over how beautiful the song is.

I have doubts that Stein sang so well because of a natural talent, since he seemed to be trying to get out of singing before getting up. I remembered that Stein was using ingestible translator to speak German, which works by attaching to the larynx and uses a neural interface. Did he sing so well because of that tech? It would certainly explain everyone’s surprise.

---

Fun Fact: In real life, [Max Lorenz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Lorenz_(tenor)) was a tenor, so the fact that Martin Stein is not should have been a dead giveaway! I'll chalk that up to artistic liberty though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Martin Stein could have sung the song all by himself even if there was no contribution from the device if there was actually any.

The only contribution of the device was to translate the lyrics of the *Edelweiss*
to German for the audience. Other than that, he sang it beautifully resembling *Max Lorenz*; all the members of the Legends were amazed but not surprised.

Stein indeed has the natural talent of singing; there were scattered [evidences](http://archiveofourown.org/works/6017008) in s1 of *Legends of Tomorrow* which evidently justify that he indeed can sing in tune and is adept in this art.

Out of the show, we all know that Victor Garber is a professional [singer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victor_Garber#Music) (and for that he can be considered for the musical crossover too).

As for the device, I can't assert on what its actual functions are.

But it can be concluded it doesn't do much more than translation from the following [conversation](http://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=557&t=29193) of Sara with Nate:

> Yeah, you know, we may not have trophies or framed letters from former presidents, but we've got a few cool toys.
>
> Including ingestible **translator**.
>
> Swallow this, you'll be able to **speak and understand any language spoken** to you.
>
> ...

Apart from that, there is no mention of its functionalities. So, following this piece of dialogue, one can live with the fact that the translator literally only *translated*  the language and nothing more.

So, in a nutshell, it was Martin Stein who sang the song and the device did its job of translating the lyrics.